# Show that the integral of an odd function over symmetric interval is always $0$ for a cubic function in the Simpson's rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, simpsons-rule

I know that the definite integral of a cubic function $f(x)$ over a symmetric interval is $0$.  I just need some clarity on why that is.

Comment: Do you mean why is Simpson's exact for cubics or why cubics (as an odd function) integrates to zero over a symmetric interval?   I think the former question is answered already on the site and has to do with the error term of Simpson's rule being expressed in terms of a 4th derivative.

Comment: I guess I am asking both, since I believe defining why Simpson's rule is exact for cubics is also incorporating the latter.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1759326/203893

Comment: Differentiate a cubic 4 times and you get zero.  Linked to a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is odd, one has that $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Consequently,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{-a}^{0}f(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{a}f(-x)\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = -\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{a}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you, the integration set up helps a lot in clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Does this plot of a cubic (odd) function over a symmetric interval help?

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you for the visual representation!